# How to store variables in Java?

Tags: java

I'm learning and I'm trying to create a simple function. The variable `p1` is supposed to generate random numbers, meanwhile the number should be added everytime to the variable `s1`.

```
class snake{
    double p1,position1;
    void testing(){
        p1=Math.random();
        p1= p1*100;
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
}
class helper extends snake{
    double s1;
    helper(){
        s1=0;
    }
    void make_changes(){
        s1=s1+p1;
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

I called the method by

```
helper h1 = new helper();
h1.testing();
h1.make_changes();
```

But when I run the code, the value doesn't add instead `s1` has the same value as `p1`.

Comment: When you add something to **zero** the result is equal to the number you add.

Comment: You're adding to `0`, so it makes sense that it is in fact adding and s1 should be the same as p1.

Comment: how have you called make_changes() second time?

Comment: Using a button, mouse click event to call the methods.

Comment: well, I need to know if you are calling make_changes() with same object (here h1). If that mouse click is creating a new object each time, then every time the answer will be p1.

Comment: totally, the mouse click is creating a new object with every click.

Comment: then the answer is as expected. Every time a new object is created. So s1 is being initialized for each new object. And you are calling make_changes() for only one time for each object.

Answer (score 1):

The code works just fine. When you initialize `helper`, `s1` is `0`. Each call to `make_changes` will add `p1` to it. The first call, which you shared in your snippet here, will make `s1` equal `0+p1`, which is just `p1`.

Comment: Yes, but when I call it for the second time, it must be added to the previous value right? Say for example, first time I call the method, its 0+50, so second time when I call the method, it must be added to 50 right, that' doesn't happen.

Comment: If you call `make_changes` **on the same** object twice, it will definitely add up. If you're creating a new object or something like that, please edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize s1 to be zero:

```
helper(){
    s1=0;
    }
```

So s1 will be p1 plus zero, which equates to p1.